# How to customize the distance between tick marks on x axis in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

How to customize the distance between tick marks on x axis in matplotlib. Something like this plot here:

[Example Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2S16.png)

Basically, I want to lengthen/shorten the spacing between tick marks based on my own personal preference.

Comment: [matplotlib.pyplot.xticks()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html) is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be log scale, you can set it by:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(np.arange(20), np.random.random(20)*3)
ax.set(
    xlim=(0.6, 20),
    xscale="log",
    xticks=(xticks := [0.6, 0.8, 1, 1.5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 15, 20]),
    xticklabels=xticks,
    ylim=(0, 3),
)
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image: DVEAZnCMwS6xdOt]

For more information read this: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xscale.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xscale